# How to Specify Neumann Conditions When Given A Heat Flux

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I’m working with the Matlab code for nonlinear heat transfer in a plate given here: 
https://www.mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/nonlinear-heat-transfer-in-a-thin-plate.html

I am only dealing with radiation so I set the h coefficient to zero. I would like to apply a boundary condition along one side that is equivalent to 5 Watts of heat entering the plate. How do I convert that to Neumann conditions?

Comment: I would say under `applyBoundaryCondition` set to `'neumann'` instead of `'dirichlet'`. But what exact value to specify is more of a physics question.

Comment: @Dylan Yeah, but for neumann they want you to give “g” where g = n dot (c cross del(u)) + qu where u is the solution and n is the unit normal. I figured that is more of a math problem to figure out what all that means.

Comment: so $n \cdot (c\nabla u) + qu = g$ is your generalized Neumann condition. Then $q=0$, $c=1$, and $g$ is either a function handle or a vector of the same length as your edge.

Comment: @Dylan Where would the 5 watts play into this?

Comment: Again, that's a physics question. That relates to the value of $g$